# How it make him able to fight metahumans while not making him a metahuman

Tags: super-powers

So, the government makes an oops. They try to create a superpowered special forces, but instead they create a group of five insane terrorist with

- Super endurance
- Near invulnerability/only heavy artillery and nukes can take them out
- Super strength
- Super speed

The 5 go on a rampage in many major cities, and the military is getting their Gluteus Maximus’s kicked trying to stop them. Their is one person, Bryan, who they think can do the job. All he has to do is inject 5 specially made needles into the Metahumans, and it will give them seizures so powerful, they will be in comas, forever. But, he has to be close up to inject them, and if he does it to one, the others will kill him. He needs to be able to match their powers, but injecting him would make him insane to.

So: How could Bryan possibly match the powers of the Metahumans

Comment: Could you be more specific about the terrorist's abilities?  How super are they?  For instance, does super strength mean "can their cars around if he puts his back into it" or "can carry an apartment complex with his little finger without noticing". A range of things these abilities can, and can't, do would be useful.  Also, I'm assuming needles means a syringe?  How big are they?

Comment: @jpgo5000: 25 tons. Their super strength limit is 25 tons. They can run 150 miles per hour

Comment: I assume those superhumans' skin is impervious to large caliber bullets and shrapnel, but vulnerable to needles. Can we put the needles into missiles?

Comment: @Alexander: The needle is made out of Talutonium

Comment: Can't we shoot those guys with Talutonium bullets?

Comment: While I appreciate the Monty Python references, I don't see this question as being on topic - you are asking for a story, not for help on world building.

Comment: What *kind* of insane? Depression? Anxiety? Psychotic? Delusional? How you trap and defang an insane super-villain depends upon the nature of their world view.

Comment: @User535733: Delusional

Comment: [Delusional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delusion) in which way? Why do you refer to them 'terrorists' if they are delusional? Do they have a real political goal (one requirement to be an actual terrorist)? Um, please edit the original question with refinements - don't bury important information in comments.

Comment: This falls under the "unstoppable villain" category of question.  Jasper I am sorry your first posts on WB were met with close votes.  Maybe you can find some help for your general scenario at this question, where @Cort Ammon poses some general type solutions.   https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/what-to-do-about-unstoppable-questions

Comment: This is getting reopen votes, but it really is off-topic:TSB.  Per our [help], asking question about the plot of your story (*especially* about the actions of a single character) rather than the rules of your world are 100% off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am vengeance! I am the night! I am Bryman!**

This reminds me of the situation that Batman was trying to deal with in the Justice League in which Batman was preparing in case the Justice League went buck-wild and needed to be stopped. Specifically the "Justice Buster"

[image]

Your requirements look like we need to handle a Superman/Wonder Woman tier opponent.

**To handle Super speed:** Use computers to make predictions of movements and then respond accordingly instead of relying on a meatbag to fight your metas (the "for him" is a reference to the flash BTW)
[image]

**To handle Near invulnerability/only heavy artillery and nukes can take them out:** Who cares? All we need to do is make the metas injected with our magic needles

**To handle Super endurance:** All this means is that we can't tire out our opponents so as long as we have enough battery life (could be good for the story), we are fine and shouldn't need to worry.

**To handle Super strength:** Dealing with this is actually how we will win the fight. In all fights previous, the terrorists haven't needed to rely on skill or finesse to win fights, but rather brute savagery. They are fast and strong enough that fighting skill really doesn't matter. Combined by the fact that they are invincible, your average terrorist leaves him/herself in a lot of vulnerable hand-to-hand positions that can be exploited. The terrorists probably don't use any weapons (and why would they when their arms are more durable than anything and can simply cut people in half with karate chops)

Don't be on the offensive, wait for your terrorists to attack and then counter punch (and while punching, eject needles from between the robo-knuckles like how wolverine releases the claws). You may also want to add little holes ALL around the armor. This way, when Bryan gets flanked, the computer can detect the metas behind the armor and shoot out an anti-meta needle in the proper location.

Answer (score 1):

Best suggestion: at the cost of sacrificing some civilian, first shock them with a sound wave, then, while they are dazed, release toxins in the air, in high concentration. Then use nanobots to inject them the coma medicine. Needles can break, aim can't be 100% accurate for all targets. A mist of nanobots will do the job by simple inspiration.

EDIT: Augmented endurance means that their skin has a greater resistance to physical injury, the skin cells having a stronger cohesion. This is true outside and inside of course.

Sensorial apparatus such as Ears, nose, eyes, are a different matter:

Nose is stronger, being covered internally in skin, but the nerves that must elaborate the smells are not, so those are sensible.

Eyelids make for a perfect protection for the eyes, but the eyes themselves are not covered in skin, and the optical nerves can be overloaded -in other words, you can cause blindness in these metahuman

Ears are higly resistant, but they still must convey sounds inside the skull. Throw in a loud enough noise and you will overload these guys to a very painful level. Just make sure that the noise is very loud and fast, don't go crescendo, just a sudden 'boom!' Everything inside the ear that is not skin-covered will disrupt.

Comment: @JBH OP doesn't describe how the government made the super terrorists, so Valerio doesn't need to explain how the sound waves shock them.

Answer (score 0):

Customize a trap for each one that feeds their particular delusion. Then use the trap to blast them. No silly needles - you want a big overkill explosion (better yet, suffocation) and DNA verification by the cleanup crew before cremating the remains.

Finally, you put the fools who approved this darned foolishness on trial. All kinds of crimes fit this bill.

For example, if Steve believes that Major League Baseball is the secret Cabal that controls the world economy, then you evacuate Cooperstown, NY and you lure Steve with the promise of proof hidden in Secret Bunker below the Baseball Hall Of Fame. When he tears the "bunker door" away, you blast without warning...and blast and blast. You might not have much of Cooperstown left, but that can be rebuilt, and your're rid of Steve.

Remember to keep the media off the story until all five have been killed, autopsied (if there's enough left), and you KNOW they'll all stay dead.

...alternately, if five major cities are *already* under attack, then evacuate those cities. When the villain is spotted, use a [fuel-air explosive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermobaric_weapon) to slow them down or chase them out into open ground. When you have one pinpointed, channel them with artillery into your (hopefully evacuated) kill zone, then nuke them with a small 3-5kt device.

The nation goes into mourning, the President gets impeached for letting it all happen and for nuking (tens of) thousands of registered voters, and the cities gets rebuilt a few months later.

Answer (score -2):

***A Mech suit***

They could put this guy in a sturdy, really sturdy, metal framed mech suit. It would be possible to increase his strength with, and with a jet pack in placement, he could fly as well. Speed would be an issue, as a mech suit can’t increase that, but all in all, it could help if they just 100% beef up the suit to be stronger